# Could not locate webpack specified in source map

Tags: angular, visual-studio, webpack

I am working in Visual Studio Code and have a site created using Angular for a class exercise. One page does not load when I click on the link to it and my browser displays the following pop-up below:

[image: Missing Webpack]

My page loads, but only displays the header, nothing for the actual form I had built. Does anyone have any suggestions on this? Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Here's as much of the error as I could input here:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Ex3a1CountriesComponent -> RegionsService]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Ex3a1CountriesComponent -> RegionsService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for RegionsService! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Ex3a1CountriesComponent -> RegionsService]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Ex3a1CountriesComponent -> RegionsService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for RegionsService! at _NullInjector.prototype.get (eval code:1218:13) at resolveToken (eval code:1516:9)

Comment: In your `app.module.ts` did you import `RegionsService` and declare it in your `providers[]` array?

Comment: I might not have in this case. I will check this as soon as I can and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! That was exactly it! I did not declare that in my array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, glad I could help! I'll add the answer so the question can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the console error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for RegionsService! Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Ex3a1CountriesComponent ->
>   RegionsService]:

You must add `RegionService` to the `providers[]` array in your `app.module.ts`